# Begriffsherleitung: "ermuntern" und "entmutigen"

Tags: vocabulary

Ich habe mich letzter Zeit gefragt, wie kommt es, dass das Wort *»ermuntern«* vor dem *t* ein *n* besitzt (ermu**n**tern) während das Wort *»entmutigen«*, wie auch das Substantiv *Mut* kein *n* enthält.

Die sind gegenteilige Begriffe und sie sind sehr ähnlich. Aber wäre es doch ein Zufall, dass sie einander ähneln. Eigentlich müsste ihre Herkunft verschieden sein.

Comment: Weil das eine von "munter" kommt, das andere aber von "mutig"? Hier eine Ähnlichkeit festzustellen, ist schon ... sehr weit hergeholt. Aber wieso soll eine Ähnlichkeit der Buchstaben etwas mit mit der Herkunft der Wörter zu tun haben?

Comment: Eigentlich habe ich beiden Wörter schon mehrere Male getroffen und mein Übersetzer ergab auf Französich "encourager" bzw. "décourager". Daher dachte ich, beide Wörter sind auch auf Deutsch etymologisch verwandt. Ich kannte das Wort "ermutigen" nicht.

Comment: "ermuntern" ist eher "remonter le moral". "encourager" entspricht hingegen "ermutigen".

Comment: Der gegenteilige Begriff von "*ent*mutigen" ist "*er*mutigen". Die zweite Worthälfte ("-mutigen") ist in beiden Fällen gleich.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ermuntern kommt von *munter* = wach, aufmerksam.
Ermutigen kommt von *mutig* = nicht ängstlich.